# Why do I get so many reads and how can I reduce them?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a school project, where I have to use Firestore for the first time, without a teacher really knowing how to do it either. I have made a budget/subscription app, where I want to create my total subscriptions for a list sort of. I have linked my Firestore and it runs as intended.

But I have like 10 subs with name, price, date and category. But I get 8k reads a minute? I have recently tried to the pay as I go plan, but I am afraid I will be charged a ton, if I don't get it fixed. I am using react.

[Firestore usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJZm2.jpg)

[My collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThWtm.jpg)

Here is the code for my crud component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { collection, getDocs, doc, deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Crud() {
  const [subs, setSubs] = useState([]);
  const subsCollectionRef = collection(db, "subs");

  const deleteSubs = async (id) => {
    const subsDoc = doc(db, "subs", id);
    await deleteDoc(subsDoc);
};

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSubs = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(subsCollectionRef);
      setSubs(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    getSubs();
  }, [subsCollectionRef]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {subs.map((subs) => {
        return (
          <div className="subField">
            {""}
            <div className="field">
            <h1>
              <Button sx={{ fontSize: 25 }} style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.888)", border: "none"}} 
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteSubs(subs.id);
                }}
                <MoreVertIcon style={{ color: "black"}} ></MoreVertIcon>
              </Button>{" "}
              &ensp;{subs.name}
            </h1>
            <h1>DKK Første betaling: {subs.payment} <br></br> Pris: {subs.price} DKK</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
);
}
```

How do I reduce it properly? I feel like I have read a lot of articles about how to reduce it, but I haven't figured anything out I completely understand. And not for my specific instance at least.
Link to [Github](https://github.com/Louigc/webapp?fbclid=IwAR1VB034Tln-orUDblr-cgmG7nlNyGROOD8yDwjPflznD-mhplPovaEUhDg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the `CollectionReference` to dependencies array. If you log something in `getSubs` function then you can see it's fetching data from Firestore multiple times. Try:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getSubs = async () => {
    console.log('getSubs function running');
    const data = await getDocs(subsCollectionRef);
    setSubs(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  getSubs();
}, []); // <-- remove subsCollectionRef
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like that has fixed the issue. Went from 8k for 30 reads now.. My wallet is secure